# Regex Not Capturing All Code Blocks in Multiline String in Rust

Tags: regex, rust, syntax-highlighting

I'm working on a Rust project where I need to apply syntax highlighting to code blocks within a multiline string. These code blocks are similar to markdown, encapsulated by triple backticks with a language identifier (e.g., "```rust"). The issue I'm encountering is that my implementation correctly captures and highlights the first code block, but fails to recognize subsequent code blocks.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

````
fn print_highlighted_response(response: &str) {
    // ... (initialize SyntaxSet and ThemeSet)

    let re = Regex::new(r"```(\w+)\n([\s\S]+?)\n```").unwrap();
    
    // ... (iterating over captures and applying syntax highlighting)
}

// ... (rest of the code)
````

I'm using the regex crate for parsing the string and syntect for syntax highlighting. The function is supposed to find each code block, apply syntax highlighting, and print it to the console. However, the first code block gets highlighted, but it doesn't stop highlighting after ```, so the rest of the response get highlighted.

Any insights into why subsequent code blocks aren't being captured would be greatly appreciated or alternative way of doing said syntax highlighting!

Here's an example of response that I need to parse. It has *normal* text and codeblock:

````
Here's a simple implementation of the Two Sum problem in Rust:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn two_sum(nums: Vec<i32>, target: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    for (i, num) in nums.iter().enumerate() {
        if let Some(n) = map.get(&(target - num)) {
            return vec![*n, i as i32];
        }
        map.insert(num, i);
    }
    vec![]
}
```

And now we have normal text again, but this is also highlighted

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn new_method(nums: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
   
}
```
````

The problem arises when due high chance of having multiple code blocks and the regex/implementation doesn't work well. Here's the full code implementation, hopefully that is allowed here.

````rust
fn print_highlighted_response(response: &str) {
    let ss = SyntaxSet::load_defaults_newlines();
    let ts = ThemeSet::load_defaults();

    let re = Regex::new(r"```(\w+)\n([\s\S]+?)\n```").unwrap();
    let mut last_end = 0;

    for cap in re.captures_iter(response) {
        print_plain_text(&response[last_end..cap.get(0).unwrap().start()]);

        let language = cap.get(1).map_or("Plain Text", |m| m.as_str());
        let code_block = cap.get(2).unwrap().as_str();
        let syntax = ss.find_syntax_by_token(language)
            .unwrap_or_else(|| ss.find_syntax_plain_text());

        let mut h = HighlightLines::new(syntax, &ts.themes["base16-ocean.dark"]);

        for line in LinesWithEndings::from(code_block) {
            let ranges: Vec<(Style, &str)> = h.highlight_line(line, &ss).unwrap();
            let escaped = as_24_bit_terminal_escaped(&ranges[..], true);
            print!("{}", escaped);
        }

        last_end = cap.get(0).unwrap().end();
    }

    print_plain_text(&response[last_end..]);
}

fn print_plain_text(text: &str) {
    print!("{}", text);
}
````

[Image for reference when running CLI in terminal (iTerm)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdcx8.png)

Comment: Would you edit your question to provide an example of what you're reading, what you expect, and what you're getting?

Comment: The link doesn't work as intended. I would assume Unix, but have to check further.

Comment: Added a image for reference. You can see that the text below code block is also highlighted.

Comment: The regex works [as demonstrated by printing `code_block`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=74bdcaac570c028ae2f3caf6fa92b266). Either there's something odd about your text input, or there's a problem elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Are you sure that the code that generates the highlighted output resets the terminal to the default style when it ends? Because if it doesn't, any text that you print afterwards will use the style it ended with…

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [as_24_bit_terminal_escaped()](https://docs.rs/syntect/latest/syntect/util/fn.as_24_bit_terminal_escaped.html):

> Note that this does not currently ever un-set the color so that the end of a line will also get highlighted with the background. This means if you might want to use println!("\x1b[0m"); after to clear the coloring.

Thus, as @Jmb suggested in the comments, the last colouring escape-code is still active at the end of the syntax-highlighted block.
Simply use `print!("{}\x1b[0m", escaped);` as suggested in the documentation.

By the way, but this is not related to your syntax-highlighting problem, since you consider `language` optional (defaults to plain-text), you should probably turn `(\w+)` into `(\w*)` or `(\w+)?`, else it won't detect the beginning of the block when the language is not specified.

Comment: Worked for the first block of code, but it wouldn't register the second one. I've tried to separate the highlight functionality to make it easier to debug, but I can't figure out why the second code block isn't functioning as wanted.

Comment: @Michael Could you give more details (maybe edit the question) in order to describe exactly what does work or does not, and **how** it does not work?